# Simple syntax to asynchronously get access to MODBUS register

Tags: python-asyncio, modbus-tcp

I am trying to run three simple tasks in parallel using asyncio and sharing global variables.
Two of them are working perfectly. One read websockets  ("async with websockets.connect("ws://192.168.1.137:9000") as websocket:" Another one access IO via a dedicated library.
I did not find any solution and the good syntax for getting AsyncModbusTCPClient running within the third task (sync MODBUS is easy to implement but would not fit within async task)
The following would just block everything:

```
async def get_var_modbus(loop):
    client = await AsyncModbusTCPClient( schedulers.ASYNC_IO,host="192.168.1.200", loop=loop, port=502, timeout=20, unit=3)
    while True:
        print("INIT")
        print("Reading coils")
        rr = await client.read_input_registers(0, 1, unit=0x03)
        print(rr.registers)
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
```

Full code below

```
from pymodbus.client.asynchronous import schedulers
from pymodbus.client.asynchronous.tcp import AsyncModbusTCPClient
import json
import time
from pypx800v5 import *
import aiohttp
import asyncio
import requests_async as requests
import numpy as np
import logging
from datetime import datetime
import websockets
import contextvars
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=DeprecationWarning) 
# SDM230 via MODBUS

SDM230A=["Voltage","Current","Active Power","Apparent Power","Reactive Power","Power Factor","Phase Angle","Frequency","Import Active Energy","Export Active Energy","Import Reactive Energy","Export Reactive Energy"]
SDM230B=["Total system power demand","Maximum total system power demand","Current system positive power demand","Maximum system positive power demand","Current system reverse power demand","Maximum system reverse power demand"]
SDM230C=["Current demand","Maximum current Demand"]
SDM230D=["Total Active Energy","Total Reactive Energy"]
SDM230Labels=SDM230A+SDM230B+SDM230C+SDM230D
SDM230Var=["Voltage","Current","ActivePower","ApparentPower","ReactivePower","PowerFactor","PhaseAngle","Frequency","ImportActiveEnergy","ExportActiveEnergy","ImportReactiveEnergy","ExportReactiveEnergy","TotalSysPowerDemand","MaxTotalSysPowerDemand","CurrentSysPositivePowerDemand","MaxSysPositivePowerDemand","CurrentSysReversePowerDemand","MaxSysReversePowerDemand","CurrentDemand","MaximumCurrentDemand","TotalActiveEnergy","TotalReactiveEnergy"]
VoltageAdd=262199
CurrentAdd=262200
ActivePowerAdd=262201
ImportActiveEnergyAdd=262202

# inversor via Websockets
TempChaudiereAdd=262198
PuissMaxChauffeauAdd=262193
WREDAdd=262194
PacBat6TLAdd=262195
totPVAdd=262196
SOC6TLAdd=262197


# shared variables

WRED= 0
PacBat6TL=0
PacPV6TL=0
Pac6TLM=0
SOC6TL=0
PAC6TL=0
totPV=0





# --------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
# configure the client logging
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------- #

logging.basicConfig()
log = logging.getLogger()
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

async def get_var_modbus(loop):
    client = await AsyncModbusTCPClient( schedulers.ASYNC_IO,host="192.168.1.200", port=502, loop=loop, timeout=20, unit=3)
    while True:
        print("INIT")
        print("Reading coils")
        rr = await client.read_input_registers(0, 1, unit=0x03)
        print(rr.registers)
        await asyncio.sleep(1)



async def get_var_socket():
    global WRED
    global PacBat6TL
    global PacPV6TL
    global Pac6TLM
    global SOC6TL
    global PAC6TL
    global totPV
    print("")
    i=0
    dict={}
    async with websockets.connect("ws://192.168.1.137:9000") as websocket:
            while True:
                i=i+1
                data=(await websocket.recv())
                try:
                    message=json.loads(data)
                except:
                    break           
                if  "product" in message:
                    if message["product"]=="ems":
                        print(message)
                        if "WRED" in message:
                            WRED=message["WRED"]                    
                        if "PacBat6TL" in message:
                            PacBat6TL=message["PacBat6TL"]
                        if "PacPV6TL" in message:
                            PacPV6TL=message["PacPV6TL"]
                            totPV=PacPV6TL
                        if "Pac6TLM" in message:
                            Pac6TLM=message["Pac6TLM"]
                            totPV=totPV+Pac6TLM
                        if "SOC6TL" in message:
                            SOC6TL=message["SOC6TL"]
                        if "PAC6TL" in message:
                            PAC6TL=message["PAC6TL"]

async def get_ipx_update():
    print("")
    i=0
    dict={}
    async with IPX800(host='192.168.1.139', api_key='API') as ipx:
            await ipx.init_config()
            while True:
                try:
                    await ipx.update_ana(WREDAdd,WRED)
                except:
                    print("ERROR")
                try:
                    await ipx.update_ana(PacBat6TLAdd,PacBat6TL)
                except:
                    print("ERROR")
                try:
                    await ipx.update_ana(totPVAdd,totPV)
                except:
                    print("ERROR")
                try:
                    await ipx.update_ana(SOC6TLAdd,SOC6TL)
                except:
                   print("ERROR")
                await asyncio.sleep(1)


def main():   
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()   
    loop.create_task(get_var_socket())
    loop.create_task(get_ipx_update())
    loop.create_task(get_var_modbus(loop))    
    loop.run_forever()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main()
    except Exception as f:
        print('main error: ', f)
        sleep(3)
```

Comment: Please explain why "The following would just block everything."  It looks like a well-behaved asycnio task to me.  It will print out registers once per second forever.  I don't see why it would block anything.

Comment: Thank you Paul, indeed I don't understand why it is blocking the asyncio loop (all the other tasks are also frozen). In any cases I found a solution using another library that is reflected in my reply.

Answer (score 1):

Using the async_modbus library (built on the top of umodbus https://pypi.org/project/async-modbus/) it works very well.
I have used this library with success.
Please find below the syntax,

```
async def get_var_modbus(loop):
   reader, writer = await asyncio.open_connection('192.168.1.200', 502)
   client = AsyncTCPClient((reader, writer))loop=loop, port=502, timeout=20, unit=3)
        while True:
            print("Reading holding registers ADAM3066")
            reply = await client.read_holding_registers(slave_id=3, starting_address=0, quantity=8)
           
            print("reply:",reply)
      

  await asyncio.sleep(1)
```

OUTPUT:

Reading holding registers ADAM3066

reply: [65535 65535 65535 65535   289 65535 65535 65535]

The ADAM 3066 is a RS-485 MODBUS RTU 1-WIRE interface connected to a MODBUS TCP gateway at 192.168.1.200, I have one sensor connected on the input 5 of ADAM 3066 which return a temperature of 28.9 degrees C